# How to drag and drop vertically and horizontally in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, react-dnd

I am new to react JS , I need to drag and drop the list vertically and horizontally at the same it , I have used **react-beautiful-dnd** , but this library only support one direction at a time , so is there any way I can drag and drop horizontal and vertically at same time ,

Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-horizontal-list-forked-1xijl8?file=/index.js

In this Suppose I need to drag Item9 to Item7 position , then If I drag Item9 over to Item7 then it behave wrong , correct behavior is Item7 position will be filled with Item9

Any help will be apricated.

NOTE : I don't want to use overflow : auto to show cursor , If Items are more then these should be start from next line rather showing scroller

Comment: It is not possible with  **react-beautiful-dnd**. Try [react-grid-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-dnd)

Comment: But this library won't support dragging after adding scroller , do you have idea about any other library

Comment: I would recommend `dnd-kit` over `react-grid-dnd`. It's more straightforward imo and gaining popularity fast